# For client authentication, why a client can access a site by the openssl certificate, belonging to an other client?

Tags: openssl

In order to test 2 way authentication, I have created a CA certificate by openssl. Then I created two certificates for two sites ("a.com" and "b.com") as server side certificares. Also I created two client certificates (client "a" and client "b"). All these certificates are signed by the same CA.

In client side, each client certificate is used to access related site. In other words, to access the site "a.com", the certificate belonging to the client "a" is needed, or the client "a" must be authenticated. Client "b" has the same situation to access the site "b.com".

In an experiment I only imported the certificate belonging to client "a", to the browser. By selecting related certificate, the site "a.com" was opened. But when I tried to open "b.com" the certificate belonging to client "a" was shown and by selecting it, I could access "b.com". It is noted that only certificate "a" was imported.

(Also it is noted that the client certificate contains the CA certificate too.)

What is the reason of this problem??

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem - this is by design.  By installing your single CA certificate on both websites 'A' and 'B' you are instructing them to trust any client certificates issued by that CA.

One way to make this work as you anticipate would be to have two different CAs - one for 'A' server and clients and another for the 'B' servers and clients.

Alternatively, Apache web server may be able to help you as it has the [`SSLRequire`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire) or [`Require`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#reqexpr) directives which can filter the client certificates for specific expressions.  You could possibly ensure that all users of website 'A' have a certificate with an OU of a specific string while users of website 'B' have a different string, and filter on those.  You could possibly filter on Certificate Policy OIDs if you've implemented those.

Nginx has [embedded variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables) which contain details of the client certificates and you may be able to use those to filter.